# MATLAB partition cell array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I have a cell array such that it is 128 characters long, i.e

```
c = {'1......128'}
```

What I'd like to do is break it up into chunks of 8, starting from the left, then put each 8-chunk piece into a new cell array. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with one line

```
mycell = repelem('a', 128); % creating the cell

newcells = cellstr(reshape(mycell{:},8,[])'); % cells with 8 characters each
```

if your cell is just `1x1` with 128 characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
valS = 1;
valE = 8;

for ii=1:(128/8)
   newC{ii,:} = c{valS:valE};
   valS = valE + 1; % after first loop valS = 9 ...
   valE = valE + 8; % after first loop valE = 16 ...
end
```

You could also use eval if you wanted to separate newC into different variables completely

Comment: This won't work, since the dimension of `c` is 1x1. You should also avoid dynamic resizing of `newC`.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
res = cell(1,16);
for ii=0:15
    res{ii} = c{1}((1:8)+ii*8);
end
```